# Redirect multiple slugs htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

My htaccess code is

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/newhome/hello-1/   [NC]
RewriteRule .*   newhome/hello-2/   [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/newhome/hello-3/   [NC]
RewriteRule .*   newhome/hello-4/   [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/newhome/hello-5/   [NC]
RewriteRule .*   newhome/hello-6/   [R=301,L]
```

Here only first condition is working but the other conditions are not working

can any one pls help me out

thank you

Comment: Check apache access logs

Comment: RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters @hjpotter92

Comment: I've tested your .htaccess and it works properly for each of the three rules... Anycase try to remove the `!-d` and `!-f` directives (all the rows), in case hello-3 and hello-5 are found as pages.

Answer (score 2):

One way to keep your rewrite logic clean is to use skip rules.  The first rule says "skip the next three if the URI already maps to a file or a directory.  If you've got no other rewrites to do in this case just replace the `SKIP=3` by an `END` if using Apache 2.4+ and `LAST` otherwise.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^                   -  [SKIP=3]

RewriteRule ^newhome/hello-1/ newhome/hello-2/   [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^newhome/hello-3/ newhome/hello-4/   [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^newhome/hello-5/ newhome/hello-6/   [R=301,L]
```

Except that this may not do what you are intending.  Consider the request `Newhome/hello-3/something`.  This will match rule 3 so the URI will be replaced by the target `newhome/hello-4/` -- that it the `something` bit will be lost. If you want to keep this content then try:

```
RewriteRule ^newhome/hello-1(/?.*) newhome/hello-2$1   [R=301,L]
```

etc.